# parsing NSMutableDictionary with required format

Tags: objective-c, arrays, parsing, nsmutabledictionary

I have an objective C object 'Obj' with an

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *obj;
```

This gets populated with data from an api in following format.

```
{
  0 =     (  0, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59 );
  1 =      (  1, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );
  2 =     (  2, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );
  3 =     (  3, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );
  4 =     (  4, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );
  5 =     (  5, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );
  6 =      (  6, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59 );
}
```

I need to parse the data and send it back as an array in following format.

```
`{
[ 0, 7, 00, 8, 59 ],
[0, 15, 00, 16, 59] , 
[0, 19, 00, 20, 59] , 
[ 1, 7, 00, 8, 59 ],
[1, 15, 00, 16, 59] , 
[1, 19, 00, 20, 59], 
……
……
[ 6, 7, 00, 8, 59 ],
[6, 15, 00, 16, 59] , 
[6, 19, 00, 20, 59] 
}`
```

Where 0,1,2,3,4,5,6 are days and rest of the information is hours and mins. so for each slot, the format is

```
`[day, from_hour, from_min, to_hour, to_min],
 [0, 7, 0, 8, 59],`
```

A day could have multiple slots or just one slot.

So far I manage to run a loop and separate each day's record as below.

```
NSMutableArray *elementArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
NSMutableArray *results =[[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
NSInteger starthour = 0 ;
NSInteger startmin = 0 ;
NSInteger endhour = 0 ;
NSInteger endmin = 0 ;
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSString *string;
int i = 0;
for ( i = 0; i <=6; i ++){
    string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
    elementArray =[Obj.obj valueForKey:string];
    starthour = [[elementArray objectAtIndex:1]integerValue];
    startmin =([[elementArray objectAtIndex:1]floatValue]-[[elementArray objectAtIndex:1]integerValue])*100;
    endhour = [[elementArray objectAtIndex:2]integerValue];
    endmin =([[elementArray objectAtIndex:2]floatValue]-[[elementArray objectAtIndex:2]integerValue])*100;
    NSNumber *day = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[string integerValue]];
    NSNumber *starthour1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)starthour];
    NSNumber *startmin1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)startmin];
    NSNumber *endhour1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)endhour];
    NSNumber *endmin1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)endmin];
    [temp addObject:day];
    [temp addObject:starthour1];
    [temp addObject:startmin1];
    [temp addObject:endhour1];
    [temp addObject:endmin1];
    [results addObject:temp];
}
```

This gives me access to each record. My thought process is saying I could solve this by going through each record and populating the required array as, 'i' being the day, then running a nest loop on each record and extracting hours and mins?

Comment: Are you getting information as JSON or any other formate?

Comment: Yes, i am getting information as JSON.

Comment: Share JSON so I can understand your problem

Comment: {
    "id" = “1234”; "temp" = "30.85";obj =    {
    0 =     (  0, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59 );  1 =      (  1, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );    2 =     (  2, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );    3 =     (  3, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );     4 =     (  4, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );  5 =     (  5, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59  );   
    6 =      (  6, "7.00", "8.59”, ”15.00”, ”16.59", "19.00", "20.59 ); };}

Comment: this is not a valid JSON, Please share valid JSON.

Comment: JSON is not an issue, I have parsing and updating the incoming data correctly. Its the when I need to send back the data I need to only send 'obj' object as array.

Comment: ok. But how can I give you any suggestion with out looking in to input values

Comment: This is how I am getting after NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error]; Now I am updating few textfields successfully with obj data coming from servers, and these values are updated by UI and obj records always being updated, so values are constantly changing.

Comment: @AbdulRehmanWarraich It seems to be the print of a `NSDictionary`, nothing too complex here.

Comment: try to use regular expression. It will save your days in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say what your *problem* actually is, i.e. you started on a solution and stopped and turned to SO, why?

Let's see if we can help you along with some pseudo-code.

You have a dictionary of arrays. the keys represent day numbers as do the first element of each array. After the first array element the elements come in pairs, each is a string containing a textual representation of hours and minutes separated by a full stop. You want and array of arrays where each element has 5 members: day number, start hour, start min, end hour, end minute, all as numbers.

A basic algorithm to handle this is two nested loops. You need somewhere to store the result:

```
results <- new empty array
```

Now you need to iterate over your dictionary:

```
for every key in sourceDictionary
   elementArray = sourceDictionary[key]
```

*[This is the loop you've written, except you generated the keys and looked them up while here we extract the keys from the dictionary. If you wish to process the keys in a particular order then generating them in that order, or extracting and sorting them, will handle that.]*

Now you'd better do some data validation, elementArray should have at least the day number and one pair of strings in it, test for that:

```
   check elementArray count > 1 and odd else handle error
```

Now you need to process each pair of strings, first access them:

```
   cursor <- 1 // element 0 is the repeated day number
   while cursor < elementArray count do
      startTime <- elementArray[cursor]
      endTime <- elementArray[cursor+1]
      cursor <- cursor + 2 // ready for next iteration
```

So now you have the day number, `key`, and the start and end times as string, `startTime` & `endTime`. Now you need to split your time strings at the full stop, returning an array of substrings:

```
      startParts <- startTime split at "."
```

More checks, did you get two parts?

```
      check startParts count is 2 else handle error
```

Now convert each substring to an integer:

```
      startHours <- parse startParts[0] as integer
      startMins <- parse startParts[1] as integer
```

And keep checking:

```
     check startHours in [0, 23] and startMins in [0, 59] else handle error
```

You've now got the five values you want, add them to your `results` array:

```
     results <- results append array of (key, startHours, startMins, endHours, endMins)
```

Now just convert that to Objective-C and fill in the details. The first loop could be a `for in` one, the second a `for(init; test; increment)` one. For splitting a string look at `NSString`'s methods, one will fit the bill. For parsing there are multiple options including `NSString` methods.

HTH

Comment: int i = 0;
   
    do{
        NSLog(@"%@",[elementArray objectAtIndex:i]);
        i++;
    }
    while( i < [elementArray count]);  This gives me each day as (
    1,
    "7.00",
    "8.59",
    "15.00",
    "16.59",
    "22.00",
    "23.59"
)

Comment: @humble_pie What is your question? From your comment you now appear to have an array of arrays, rather then a dictionary of arrays (so `sourceDictionary` in the answer correspond with `elementArray` in your comment and `elementArray` in the answer corresponds with `[elementArray objectAtIndex:i]` in your comment). So where you have `NSLog` in your comment corresponds to the stage in the answer starting "Now you'd better do some data validation...". Is there something after that point which is causing you difficulty? If so what, what have you tried, etc.

Comment: @humble_pie **Edit your question** to provide further details as above, **do not** try to squeeze code into comments. You may add a comment to this this answer saying you've added information to your question if you wish.

Comment: I have updated the code. Basically I am extracting keys and values from dictionary into element's array as you suggested. Then In the for loop try to parse each day and time slots but it seems to run multiple times for each day

Comment: i got it working, but code looks a bit messy, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with desired output, but code looks messy, could be made elegant.

```
` NSMutableArray *elementArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
    NSMutableArray *results =[[NSMutableArray alloc ]init];
    NSInteger starthour = 0 ;
    NSInteger startmin = 0 ;
    NSInteger endhour = 0 ;
    NSInteger endmin = 0 ;

    NSNumber *starthour1 ;
    NSNumber *startmin1  ;
    NSNumber *endhour1 ;
    NSNumber *endmin1 ;
    NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSString *string;
    int i = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i <=6; i ++){
        string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
        elementArray =[Obj.obj valueForKey:string];
        starthour = [[elementArray objectAtIndex:1]integerValue];
        startmin =([[elementArray objectAtIndex:1]floatValue]-[[elementArray objectAtIndex:1]integerValue])*100;
        endhour = [[elementArray objectAtIndex:2]integerValue];
        endmin =([[elementArray objectAtIndex:2]floatValue]-[[elementArray objectAtIndex:2]integerValue])*100;
        NSNumber *day = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[string integerValue]];
           starthour1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)starthour];
           startmin1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)startmin];
           endhour1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)endhour];
           endmin1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)endmin];
        [temp addObject:day];
        [temp addObject:starthour1];
        [temp addObject:startmin1];
        [temp addObject:endhour1];
        [temp addObject:endmin1];
        [results addObject:[temp copy]];



        [temp removeAllObjects];

        starthour = [[elementArray objectAtIndex:3]integerValue];
        startmin =([[elementArray objectAtIndex:3]floatValue]-[[elementArray objectAtIndex:3]integerValue])*100;
        endhour = [[elementArray objectAtIndex:4]integerValue];
        endmin =([[elementArray objectAtIndex:4]floatValue]-[[elementArray objectAtIndex:4]integerValue])*100;

        starthour1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)starthour];
        startmin1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)startmin];
        endhour1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)endhour];
        endmin1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)endmin];
        [temp addObject:day];
        [temp addObject:starthour1];
        [temp addObject:startmin1];
        [temp addObject:endhour1];
        [temp addObject:endmin1];
        [results addObject:[temp copy]];



        [temp removeAllObjects];
        starthour = [[elementArray objectAtIndex:5]integerValue];
        startmin =([[elementArray objectAtIndex:5]floatValue]-[[elementArray objectAtIndex:5]integerValue])*100;
        endhour = [[elementArray objectAtIndex:6]integerValue];
        endmin =([[elementArray objectAtIndex:6]floatValue]-[[elementArray objectAtIndex:6]integerValue])*100;

        starthour1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)starthour];
        startmin1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)startmin];
        endhour1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)endhour];
        endmin1 = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:(int)endmin];
        [temp addObject:day];
        [temp addObject:starthour1];
        [temp addObject:startmin1];
        [temp addObject:endhour1];
        [temp addObject:endmin1];
        [results addObject:[temp copy]];



        [temp removeAllObjects];
`
```

The output is what I wanted looks like below.

> (
>           (
>           0,
>           7,
>           0,
>           8,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           0,
>           15,
>           0,
>           16,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           0,
>           19,
>           0,
>           20,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           1,
>           7,
>           0,
>           8,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           1,
>           15,
>           0,
>           16,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           1,
>           22,
>           0,
>           23,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           2,
>           7,
>           0,
>           8,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           2,
>           15,
>           0,
>           16,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           2,
>           19,
>           0,
>           20,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           3,
>           7,
>           0,
>           8,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           3,
>           15,
>           0,
>           16,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           3,
>           22,
>           0,
>           23,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           4,
>           7,
>           0,
>           8,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           4,
>           15,
>           0,
>           16,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           4,
>           19,
>           0,
>           20,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           5,
>           7,
>           0,
>           8,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           5,
>           15,
>           0,
>           16,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           5,
>           22,
>           0,
>           23,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           6,
>           7,
>           0,
>           8,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           6,
>           15,
>           0,
>           16,
>           59
>       ),
>           (
>           6,
>           19,
>           0,
>           20,
>           59
>       )
>   )

Comment: It does appear to work according to your output, so well done. You might think it is untidy but there are some more problematic issues. First you have used floating point math as part of parsing two *integers* which happen to be separated by a full stop. Floating point math works in binary and so you are relying on the minute value being correct after it has been represented as a binary fraction (i.e. `.59` as a decimal fraction is 5/10 + 9/100, as a binary fraction it is 1/2 + 1/16 + 1/64 + ...). It is much better to parse integer values as integers. (cont)

Comment: Next in your question you have stated "A day could have multiple slots or just one slot", your solution essentially contains an "unrolled loop", repeating the same code 3 times and fixing the number of slots at 3. If you do have data with less than 3 time slots your code will fault. You would be better testing for the number of slots and using a loop so you both avoid faulting and repeating code. HTH

Comment: Yes floating point logic isn't great. I spent more and 2 hours finding better way of splitting the strings after decimal but couldn't get it working. On your second point, I made sure elsewhere in my code to always supply 3 time slots.

Comment: You might find [this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-componentsseparatedbystring?language=objc) helpful.